# How to make a matrix heatmap with circles instead of squares?

Tags: plotting

is there any way to make a matrix heatmap with circles instead of squares? I tried ArrayPlot and MatrixPlot but I didn't know how to make such a replacement. Thanks for sharing your ideas. Many thanks!

```
ArrayPlot[{RandomInteger[10, 10], RandomInteger[10, 10], RandomInteger[10, 10], RandomInteger[10, 10]}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

I intend to make a matrix heatmap in the following style.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a potential starting point using [`PointValuePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointValuePlot.html):

```
With[{data = RandomInteger[100, {10, 4}]},
  PointValuePlot[
    Flatten@ MapIndexed[#2 -> #1 &, data, {2}],
    "Size", BubbleSizes -> {0.015, 0.25},
    ColorFunction -> "Temperature",
    FrameTicks -> {Range[10], Range[10]},
    AspectRatio -> Divide@@ Reverse@ Dimensions[data]
  ]
]
```

[image: pointvalueplot output]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'll check this new function!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
c = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[{0., 1}]], Disk[{i, j}, .5]}, {i, 1, 
    20}, {j, 1, 10}];

Legended[
 Graphics[Flatten@c,ImageSize->640,Frame->True],
 Placed[BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}], After]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your great help! I'll try your solution as well.